# SQL - Add Column With Count()

Tags: sql, group-by, common-table-expression

I want to simply add a column to the results given below that comes from "select count(*) ... group by possession".  So it should still retain the same number of rows, and have this added column.  I was told to look into a lateral join but I don't understand how to do it especially in the context of my query which has the CTE

QUERY

```
select
 *
 from (
       with possession_change as (
         select
           (lag(possession,1) over (order by id)) as last_possession,
           possession,
           clock
         from plays
         where
          game_id in (583615)
          and league = 3
          and period in (0,1)
         )
       select * from possession_change
      ) stuff
;
```

RESULTS

```
last_possession | possession | clock 
-----------------+------------+-------
                 |          0 |  3600
               0 |          0 |  3600
               0 |          0 |  3600
               0 |          0 |  3600
               0 |          1 |  3561
               1 |          1 |  3561
               1 |          1 |  3561
               1 |          1 |  3449
               1 |          1 |  3449
               1 |          0 |  3396
               0 |          0 |  3396
               0 |          0 |  3396
```

DESIRED RESULTS

```
last_possession | possession | clock | possession_count
-----------------+------------+-------
                 |          0 |  3600  | 7
               0 |          0 |  3600  | 7
               0 |          0 |  3600  | 7
               0 |          0 |  3600  | 7
               0 |          1 |  3561  | 5
               1 |          1 |  3561  | 5
               1 |          1 |  3561  | 5
               1 |          1 |  3449  | 5
               1 |          1 |  3449  | 5
               1 |          0 |  3396  | 7
               0 |          0 |  3396  | 7 
               0 |          0 |  3396  | 7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `count over`:

```
select
    lag(possession,1) over (order by id) as last_possession,
    possession,
    clock,
    count(*) over (partition by possession) cnt
from plays
where
    game_id in (583615)
    and league = 3
    and period in (0,1)
```